# Choose letter in alpha enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I was wondering how to choose the letter in an alpha enumerated list.  This is what I have so far

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]

    % Part (a)
    \item

    % Part (d)
    \item

    % Part (f)
    \item

\end{enumerate}
```

the output gives me

```
(a)
(b)
(c)
```

but I want it to give me

```
(a)
(d)
(f)
```

Is there another argument I have to provide in the `\begin` statement? or can I give each individual `\item` and argument?

Comment: Is it really "enumerated" if there is nothing sequential about the labels?  By the way, welcome to the site.  And you can say `\item[(d)]` to override the default label.

Comment: I see your point, but it's for a HW assignment and instead of having to type out 5.1.1a, 5.1.1d, 5.1.1f I'd like to just use an "enumerated" list

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- there's a down-side to giving an optional argument to `\item` -- if you want to hyperlink it, that won't work, although `\label` and `\ref` will probably be resolved correctly.  `hyperref` will only link to elements identified by a counter, and by using the optional value on `\item`, that removes it from counter control.

Comment: @user75287 -- before each non-continuous `\item`, increase the value of the relevant counter by the necessary increment.  in this case, that should probably be `\addtocounter{enumi}{1}`.

Comment: You could, for those cases where needed, bump the counter (which will make barbara happy): `% Part (a)
    \item \addtocounter{enumi}{2}

    % Part (d)
    \item \addtocounter{enumi}{1}

    % Part (f)
    \item`.  If the list is nested, the relevant counter might be `enumii` or `enumiii` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you can  manually specify the value of the label. If your labels have some regularity, you can add it to the optional argument of the `enumerate` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)]
\item A first item.
\item[(d)] Second item.
\item[(f)] A third item.
\end{enumerate}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{enumerate}[label = (\alph*)\addtocounter{enumi}{2}]
\item A first item.
\item Second item. 
\item A third item. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following allows you to set the next item to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \AlphToNum { m }
{
   \int_from_alph:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nextitem}[1]{\setcounter{enum\romannumeral\enit@depth}{\numexpr\AlphToNum{#1}-1}}
\newcommand{\thisitem}[1]{\nextitem{#1}\item}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item % Part (a)
  \item % Part (b)
  \item % Part (c)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item % Part (a)
  \nextitem{d}
  \item % Part (d)
  \thisitem{f} % Part (f)
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

`\AlphToNum{<alph>}` converts `<alph>` to a number (you can use capital letters as well, like `D` or `F`, or even `-F`). This conversion capability is thanks to [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3).

`\nextitem` "prepares" the next `\item`, while `\thisitem` sets the next item. It depends on your preference.

Cross-referencing is maintained, as one would expect.